# What is the difference between .py and .pyc files?

Tags: python, file

I have noticed `.pyc` files spontaneously being generated when some `.py` file of the same name gets run. What is the difference between `.py` and `.pyc` files?

Also, I find that having `.pyc` files lying around clutters up space. Should one delete `.pyc` files? Or is there a benefit and/or necessity to having them around?

UPDATE: Here are 2 answered questions that are related to my question

[If Python is interpreted, what are .pyc files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files)

[Why are main runnable Python scripts not compiled to pyc files like modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878479/python-pyc-files-main-file-not-compiled)

**This Question is not a Duplicate**

*Reason 1: Because I am asking what the difference between these two files are. The question S.Lott found named 'If Python is interpreted, what are .pyc files?' is not asking what the difference between .py and .pyc files are. It is asking what .pyc files are.*

*Reason 2: Because my secondary questions 'Should one delete `.pyc` files? Or is there a benefit and/or necessity to having them around?' provide even more information on .pyc files and how one should handle them.*

*Reason 3: Because when a beginner Python programmer like myself wants to find out **What is the difference between .py and .pyc files?** , they will have no problem finding out the answer as they will be guided directly to my question. This helps reduce search time since the question is right to the point.*

Comment: There is a discussion on SO related to this area: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878479/python-pyc-files-main-file-not-compiled

Comment: http://net-informations.com/python/iq/pyc.htm

Answer (score 89):

`.pyc` contain the compiled bytecode of Python source files. The Python interpreter loads `.pyc` files before `.py` files, so if they're present, it can save some time by not having to re-compile the Python source code. You can get rid of them if you want, but they don't cause problems, they're not big, and they may save some time when running programs.

Comment: "they may save some time when running programs." you are wrong here, check the doc (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html) : "A program doesn’t run any faster when it is read from a .pyc or .pyo file than when it is read from a .py file; the only thing that’s faster about .pyc or .pyo files is the speed with which they are loaded."

Comment: @tzzzzz: True, but load time will affect total speed of execution, especially for smaller programs where a higher proportion of time is spent loading/compiling the source code.

Comment: also, pyc works independently from py, once compiled to bytocode the py source is not needed

Answer (score 18):

Python compiles the `.py` and saves files as `.pyc` so it can reference them in subsequent invocations.

There's no harm in deleting them, but they will save compilation time if you're doing lots of processing.

Comment: How does Python know to read the .pyc file instead of the .py file, if one makes a change in the .py file? Simply date-modification checks? Or is it more advanced?

Comment: @MichaelButler Straight timestamps check.

Answer (score 12):

> A program doesn't run any faster when it is read from a ".pyc" or ".pyo" file than when it is read from a ".py" file; the only thing that's faster about ".pyc" or ".pyo" files is the speed with which they are loaded.

http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/node43.html