# Running a single Python script with different parameter values

Tags: python

I have a Python script called `a.py`, which takes 1 parameter from the command line. `a.py` is invoked as follows: `python a.py 1`, where `1` is the parameter value. Now, suppose I run `a.py` with 3 different parameter values on a single machine like this:

```
python a.py 1 &
python a.py 2 &
python a.py 3
```

I only see one `a.pyc` file. I wonder why there is only one `a.pyc` file since I invoke the program 3 times with 3 different parameters values, should there be 3 `a.pyc` files (maybe with different names)? If not, the `a.pyc` file couldn't contain all 3 parameters values, so where are the parameter values (i.e., `1,2,3`) stored?

Comment: `a.pyc` doesn't store any parameters passed to the program... (This can actually be a vulnerability as then anything you pass as a parameter, maybe something malicious, will be written to this file.) Why would you expect Python to create 3 copies of this file? It creates one `a.pyc` and then runs it with different arguments.

Comment: why do you want to run it 3 times? do you want to give 3 params as input to a single file?

Answer (score 0):

please refer this [Difference py and pyc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3918716/2466407)

Basically parameters you are passing is just a system argument.
When Py file is get compiled it converted into Byte Code, Where System argument is just a input parameter from command line so there will be single Pyc file for the same code base.

Comment: OK but if I modify `a.py` and run it simultaneously with the first script (the original `a.py`), then the first script would produce erroneous output, yes? Since I think after we run the modified `a.py`, the `a.pyc` is changed which affects the first script.