# Is there the difference between runtime of .py and .pyc files?

Tags: python, compilation, interpreter, pyc

I know about `.pyc` files (compiled `.py` file) and difference between them:
[difference between .py and .pyc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3918689/3702377)

---

### My question is:

- Is there difference between **runtime** of `.py` and `.pyc` files or
  those **benchmarks**?
- And is using `.pyc` instead of `.py` **reliable** ?

Thanks in advance.

---

Comment: `pyc` loads faster but does not run faster.

Comment: @KlausD. what do you means of load?

Answer (score 1):

`.pyc` contains byte code which is essentially what the interpreter compiles the source code into.Generating byte code is essentially something that is done for optimisation by which way your code can be run directly without having to create an executable. This makes things faster.

Answer (score 0):

**I think** when you run a `.py` file, it **takes few time** for creating its `.pyc` file.

And when you straight run `.pyc` file does not need to take a time for creating `.pyc` file and then runtime of `.py` and `.pyc` files are the same.