# Is there a way to compare 2 Pypi package sourecode difference

Tags: pypi

I have already built pypi package stored on pypi server few days back. Now I want to compare source code diff between already built pypi package and recent code built today. Is there any way to this?

I want to compare already built pypi package and newly build code. And If there is any difference in source code then only create a new package and upload it to pypi server

Comment: **Why do you want to do that?** Why can't you use some good enough package manager? Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55862296/edit) your question with additional motivation: it smells badly as some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have only Python [bytecodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode), you cannot get the corresponding source code (that hypothetical transformation is called [decompilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler), and is not possible in general; read e.g. about [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem)). Since any translation (such as the one done by the `python` program) from [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) to bytecode is *losing some information* (e.g. name of local variables, comments explaining the intent of the code).

Equality of the *behavior* of functions by [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) of their source code (and the *observable behavior* of your code is what you really care about) is an [undecidable problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem). Learn more about [λ-calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), it is deeply related to that question.

The [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) (by definition, the preferred form of code on which developers work) is not only for computers, but mostly for fellow developers: in other words, most of its value and its meaning is a social one (and that is what  [free software](https://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software) is about). Read more about the [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)) of programs.

For example, renaming a variable from `i` to `x` may convey the implicit hypothesis that the intended [dynamic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language) runtime type of the value of that variable was an integer, and becomes a floating point.

Maybe you want some kind of [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) (or some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system, if you deal with source code, or some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, if you build then install software out of it). Python has [something](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) to manage packages. The [`scons`](https://scons.org/) build automation uses Python, but there are many other build automation tools, [GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) being a common one (that you could use to drive compilation from `.py` source files to [`.pyc` bytecode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3918689/841108) files and their [installation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installation_(computer_programs))). For version control, I recommend [`git`](https://git-scm.com/).

PS. Your question is very unclear and smells like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).