# is there any kind of performance gain while using .pyc files in python?

Tags: python, pyc

We can write a piece of python code and put it in already compiled ".pyc" file and use it. I am wondering that is there any kind of gain in terms of performance or it is just a kind of modular way of grouping the code.

Thanks a lot

Comment: possible duplicate of [If Python is interpreted, what are .pyc files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files)

Comment: For further reading, please refer to [why is the 'running' of .pyc files not faster compared to .py files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773362/why-is-the-running-of-pyc-files-not-faster-compared-to-py-files)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no performance gain over the course of your program. It only improves the startup time.

> A program doesn't run any faster when it is read from a ‘.pyc’ or
>   ‘.pyo’ file than when it is read from a ‘.py’ file; the only thing
>   that's faster about ‘.pyc’ or ‘.pyo’ files is the speed with which
>   they are loaded.

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/CompiledPythonfiles.html

And pyo files being the next optimization just remove doc strings from your code.

Comment: .pyo files have assert statements stripped out (and potentially other optimisation) but might not have doc strings removed; it depends whether you use '-O' or '-OO'.

Comment: Right, thanks. Yes its also assert statements, and it does depend on the level of optimization you pass. Overall though, its still a minimal runtime improvement.

Comment: @ealeon no idea about concrete numbers. It just may provide a benefit to startup time of a program when many py files don't have to be parsed and compiled to bytecode

Comment: right, but w/o numbers how do i justify creating .pyc or turning it off :P

Comment: You test and measure, yourself, instead of asking for benchmarks to drive your decision :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about .pyc files (very minor gain is at least not creating .pyc files again), but there's a '-O' flag for the Python interpreter which produces optimised bytecode (.pyo files).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply because the first time you execute a .py file, it is compiled to a .pyc file. 
So basically you have to add the compilation time. Afterwards, the .pyc file should be always used.

Answer (score 0):

You will gain the fraction of a second it took the Python runtime to parse and compile the source into bytecode, which only happens on first run/import.

You will lose portability.

See [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/pytut/CompiledPythonfiles.html).

> A program doesn't run any faster when it is read from a ‘.pyc’ or
>   ‘.pyo’ file than when it is read from a ‘.py’ file; the only thing
>   that's faster about ‘.pyc’ or ‘.pyo’ files is the speed with which
>   they are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer of this question: [Why are main runnable Python scripts not compiled to pyc files like modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878479/python-pyc-files-main-file-not-compiled).

> When a module is loaded, the py file is "byte compiled" to pyc files.
>   The time stamp is recorded in pyc files. This is done not to make it
>   run faster but to load faster