# Why is the 'running' of .pyc files not faster compared to .py files?

Tags: python, pyc

I know the difference between a .py and a .pyc file. My question is **not** about **how**, **but** about **why** According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#compiled-python-files):

> A program doesn’t run any faster when it is read from a .pyc or .pyo
>   file than when it is read from a .py file; the only thing that’s
>   faster about .pyc or .pyo files is the speed with which they are
>   loaded.

.pyc files load imports faster. But after loading the 'running' part of .pyc files takes the same time as the 'running' part in .py files? Why is is this? I would expected that

- bit code (.pyc) is closer to the Python Virtual Machine and thus runs faster
- .py files are being compiled to .pyc before they are being executed. This takes an extra step and thus costs time.

My question: After the import part, Why does the  running part of .pyc files doesn't speed up execution compared to .py files?

Comment: ".py files are being compiled to .pyc before they are being executed. This takes an extra step and thus costs time." Yes, and that's also exactly why they run just as fast: because "running" means the part **after** that step, and after that step **there is only the compiled code**. "After the import part, Why does the running part of .pyc files doesn't speed up execution compared to .py files?" Because the loading is the part that they can speed up.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you run a `.py` file, it is first compiled to bytecode, then executed. The loading of such a file is slower because for a `.pyc`, the compilation step has already been performed, but after loading, the same bytecode interpretation is done.

In pseudocode, the Python interpreter executes the following algorithm:

```
code = load(path)
if path.endswith(".py"):
    code = compile(code)
run(code)
```

Comment: To compile a .py file programmatically:

import py_compile

py_compile.compile('Hello.py')

- this generates Hello_cpython-36.pyc (based on the implementation you are using)

Answer (score 12):

The way the programs are *run* is always the same.  The compiled code is interpreted.

The way the programs are *loaded* differs.  If there is a current `pyc` file, this is taken as the compiled version, so no compile step has to be taken before running the command.  Otherwise the `py` file is read, the compiler has to compile it (which takes a little time) but then the compiled version in memory is interpreted just like in the other way.

Answer (score 0):

The running time of the program is when everything is compiled and the program is executed. Having files already compiled does not speed up execution time, it only speeds up the time TO GET to execution, (compiling all the files into bytecode).

Thus in your second point it would be incorrect to factor compilation time in execution time. When we measure the execution time of programs from varying different languages, all the files are already compiled and ready to go.